# Bounding a function on sets with a prescribed measure

Tags: measure-theory

In the proof of a lemma in a paper I'm reading the following is claimed.

> Let $f$ be a measurable function with $f(t) \geq 0$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$ and $\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt = 1$.  Let $k$ be a fixed number with $0 \leq k < 1$.  Then we can find an $E \subseteq [0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure $\mu(E) = k$ and a number $p$ such that $$f(t) \leq p \,\text{ for }\, t \in E \,\text{ and }\, f(t) \geq p \,\text{ for }\, t \notin E.$$

Why can we always find such $E$ and $p$ at the same time?

---

The paper is:

De Bruijn, N. G.
On some Volterra integral equations of which all solutions are convergent.
Nederl. Akad. Wetensch., Proc. 53, (1950) 813–821 = Indagationes Math. 12, 257–265 (1950).

I've paraphrased it slightly but the statement is essentially the first claim in the proof of Lemma 2.

Comment: As written, it's false. $f \equiv 1$ is a counterexample (for every $k \notin \{0,1\}$). Is it perhaps "$f(t) \geqslant p$ for $t \notin E$"?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, you're definitely right.  I'm trying to see how I've misinterpreted the claim and I'll post an image of the part of the paper if I can't.

Comment: @DanielFischer, you're right!  Though the strict inequality is written, it isn't required in the proof, only $\geq$.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: Then we still have the problem for $k = 1$, either we must allow $p = \infty$, or we must assume $f$ bounded to achieve it for $k = 1$.

Comment: The question has been edited to exclude $k=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $k<1$, I think it is true:

Let $g(x)=\mu (f^{-1}([0,x)))$. Then $g$ is an increasing function because if $x<y$ then $f^{-1}([0,x) ) \subset f^{-1}([0,y) )$. This has only countably many discontinuities and they are all jump discontinuities.

If $g(x)=k$, then $x=p$ and $E=f^{-1}([0,p))$.

Suppose $g$ jumps over the value $k$. That is, $\lim_{x\to p^-} g(x)<k$  $\lim_{x\to p^+} g(x)>k$. Suppose $g(p)<k$. Then $\lim_{x\to p^+} g(x)>k$ tells us that $\mu (f^{-1}(\{p\}))>0.$ Find a subset $A$ of $f^{-1}(\{p\})$ with measure $k-g(p)$. Then $E=A\cup f^{-1}([0,p))$. Similarly for $g(p)>k$.

Note that the integral condition guarantees that $f$ is bounded almost everywhere so these inverse images get a set of full measure.

Comment: My measure theory is a little rusty.  Could you expand on why we can find the subset $A$?  I get that $\mu(f^{-1}(\{p\})) \geq k - g(p)$, so I guess I'm asking whether, given some set $G$ and some $\ell$ with $\mu(G) > \ell \geq 0$, can we always find $H \subseteq G$ with $\mu(H) = \ell$?

Comment: This is a property of non-atomic measures which can be viewed as a corollary of Lyapunov's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_measure#Lyapunov.27s_theorem

Comment: Maybe a better reference: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226179/x-is-locally-compact-hausdorff-space-mu-is-borel-regular-measure-how-to-p/226258#226258

Comment: Awesome.  Many thanks, both for your answer and for the references!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the statement is true: Choose a function $f: [0,1]\to (0,\infty)$ such that $f$ is continuous in $(0,1)$, $\lim_{t\to 0} f(t)=\infty$ and $\int_0^1 f(t)dt=1$.

Take $k=1$ and suppose that there exist $E$ with $|E|=1$ and $p>0$ such that $$f(t)\leq p,\ \forall\ t\in E \tag{1}$$

From $(1)$, $\lim_{t\to 0} f(t)=\infty$ and the continuity, we conclude that there exist $\delta>0$ such that $E\subset (\delta,1)$, which is N absurd, because $|E|=1$.

Comment: Thanks, I agree.  In fact the case $k=1$ was not explicitly allowed, so we probably have to avoid it for the reason you give.